# Sidekiq workers use too many mongo connections

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper, sidekiq

I'm running Sidekiq under MRI 1.9.3, and using MongoMapper as my ORM.

My Sidekiq workers are frequently dying with the following exception:

```
Mongo::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain connection within 15.0 seconds. 
The max pool size is currently 40; consider increasing the pool size or timeout.
```

Sidekiq is configured to run with a concurrency level of 30.

As you can see, I've set my Mongo connection pool to 40 with a timeout of 15 seconds, thinking that should give me more than enough mongo connections for all my active Sidekiq threads.

However this exception happens frequently, particularly when the number of active workers approaches the maximum.

I've seen something mentioned about this with respect to Mongoid on the Sidekiq wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#too-many-connections-to-mongodb

However Mongoid uses a different mongo driver from MongoMapper, so the kiqstand middleware doesn't help.

MongoMapper uses the official mongo driver which is supposed to be thread safe and employs a connection pool.

What needs to happen in the Sidekiq server middleware to free up MongoMapper connections when a thread finishes?

Comment: Do you define a new connection in each job? Like `MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(...)`? If so maybe you should move this out of the job class, like in the root module of your gem?